# EHCache write-behind possible issue if system crashes

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

New to caching...

I was looking into Spring's EHCache and I found its "write-behind" new feature very interesting. Data is written to the cache first and then to the underlying database in an asynchronous way reducing the load on the database through time-shifting, rate-limiting, or conflation (by the way, do other caches have the same capabilities?). It just sounds great for what I need.

Now..

What happens if my server/system/cache crashes badly (i mean really badly) for any reasons? Would I loose data stored in the cache that is waiting to be loaded into the database? Can I prevent this from happening by using 'Big Memory' or 'Disk Store' and would these options be convenient?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You will lose a small portion of data any way you do this, unless the source of the data has some kind of error correctino

Answer (score 1):

A Terracotta cluster would give you a durable write-behind queue http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/write-through-caching#using-a-combined-read-through-and-write-behind-cache
and http://vimeo.com/21193026

Comment: Terracotta allows configuring to durable writes to disk...meaning its transactional and data file is not corrupted. You can even kill process and cache data would survive on the next restart (will be loaded back from disk)

Answer (score 0):

> Would I loose [sic] data stored in the cache that is waiting to be loaded into the database?

Yes, you would.  This the trade-off you have to accept with "write-behind" caches.

If you need transactional integrity, you need to write directly to the transactional backing store, and then either flush the entry from the cache ("write-back"), or update the cache synchronously with the write to the data store ("write-through").

Comment: Thanks skaffman, I believe that caching to disk memory would prevent this issue from happening though, right? I'm just considering performance trade offs but I'm not sure if it makes a lot of sense to have a slower cache..